# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-e^{1-x})^n$ and question on convergence in distribution

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find some positive limit for
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-e^{1-x})^n$$
for some value of $x$ which could be on the form $x=\frac{t}{n}$ or something like that. Can anyone see some smart way to define $x$ such that we get a positive limit which I can use.

If I use $x=1-ln(t/n)$ than I get:
$$P(X_n \leq ln(t/n)) \to e^{-t}$$

Then my question is can I find some sequence $b_n (X_n -a_n)$ s.t. the sequence is convergent in distribution?

Answer (score 3):

If $c$ is a constant. then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^n=e^{-c}$.

So choosing $x=\ln n$ will give you a positive limit.  You can alter this somewhat by using $k+\ln n$, where $k$ is a constant. But you are pretty much stuck with rate of growth $\log n$ is you want a finite non-zero limit.

Comment: What does it then mean
$$P(X_n-ln(n) \leq 1) \to e^{-e}$$
How can I solve those constants to get convergence in distribution?

Comment: Sholud be a plus there above, generally for $\epsilon = ln(n/t)$ we get
$$P(X_n-1+ln(n) \leq ln(t)) \to e^{-et}$$
as n goes to infinity.

Comment: I think you will need the additional freedom given by the $k$ in the answer to get information about the behaviour of $X_n$. But I do not even know the actual problem that gave rise to the question.

Comment: Well the actual problem is we have $X_{(n)}=max\{X_1,..,X_n\}$ where $X_i$ is exponentially distrubuted with $\lambda=1$. Then I want to find a sequence of numbers $a_n$ s.t.
$$X_{(n)} -a_n$$
is convergent in distribution and I want to find the limiting distribution.

Comment: I have now by plugging $\epsilon =t+ln(n)$ that
$$P(X(n) \leq 1-t-ln(n)) \to e^{-e^{1+t}}$$
But I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: I have not checked your work. But if we sort of normalize $X(n)$ by putting $$Y(n)=X(n)-(-\ln(n))$ we have what looks like a cdf.

Comment: Do you know cdf of what distribution?

Comment: No, but I think I have seen it before, in a list of distributions.

Comment: Remembered, I am kind of slow! Sometimes called double exponential, more usually Gumbel.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose $x=1- \ln \frac{t}{n}$, where $t$ is a constant, then 
$$
1-e^{1-x} = 1-\frac{t}{n},
$$
and your limit will be
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{t}{n})^n=e^{-t}.
$$